# Core Data NSPredicate checking for BOOL value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, core-data, nspredicate

I am currently having an issue pulling all data from db whereby i.e 1 parameter is TRUE.

I am using `NSPredicate` and below is a sample code

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = managedObjectContext_;

if (!context) {
    // Handle the error.
    NSLog(@"ERROR CONTEXT IS NIL");
}

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"tblcontent" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext_];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"bookmarked == YES"];

[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

I tried setting predicatewithformat to almost everything but it still does not pull out bookmarks which have a `YES` value.

I even tried `(@"bookmarked == %d",YES)` but with not luck. I don't want to have to get the whole array and then filter it manually by doing `if(object.bookmarked == YES)` .....blabla.

I will really appreciate some help.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 71):

Based on Apple Document [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html), we can use the following two methods to compare Boolean:

```
NSPredicate *newPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"anAttribute == %@",[NSNumber numberWithBool:aBool]];
NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"anAttribute == YES"];
```

However, the above predicate cannot get out the ones with empty `anAttribute`. To deal with an empty attribute, you need the following method according to Apple document [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html):

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName = nil"]; // it's in the document
```

or

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName == nil"]; // == and = are interchangeable here
```

Answer (score 31):

Sneaking in with the Swift 3/4 answer:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "boolAttribute == %@", NSNumber(value: true))
```

We have to use NSNumber apparently because a literal bool is not acceptable per Apple.

[Stolen from here ;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169121/how-to-write-a-bool-predicate-in-core-data)

Comment: OMG! You saved my life... WHY is it working with `false` but not with `true` ... It took me a while to even find the line that makes my app crash, because the stack trace was not helpful at all.

Answer (score 13):

For some reason, Flow's solution would not work for me:

```
NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"anAttribute == YES"];
```

However, this did:

```
NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"anAttribute == 1"];
```

Comment: Also for my case Flow's solution didn't work. It worked with anAttribute == 1

Answer (score 10):

I'm late to the party and as discussed using 0 and 1's is the way to go however there is a better way to show this by using NSNumber BOOL literals like @YES or @NO. It converts it to a 1 or a 0 but is more visually friendly.

```
NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"anAttribute == %@", @NO];
```

Answer (score 5):

Core Data entities **does not have any default values** when you create attributes for Entity, so to make your predicate work you should either set default values for boolean attributes or use predicate in this way.

If you **provide default value** (NO or YES) for any boolean property of Entity then use predicate like this

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"boolAttribute == %@", @NO];
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"boolAttribute == NO", @NO];
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"boolAttribute == %0"];
```

If you **do not** have default values or some of Entities was already created without default values then to filter by **false** value use this sentence:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"boolAttribute == %@ || boolAttribute == nil", @NO];
```

Comment: The null check is important, especially as once the fetch is done it can appear that bool entries are false, when in fact they are null

Answer (score 2):

Swift:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == NO",#keyPath(MyEntity.isOccupied))
```

or

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == NO",\MyEntity.isOccupied)
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned what results you're getting. Two things that are missing from your code listing is where you set your request's entity and where you actually ask the context to execute the fetch request. I'd start there.

Comment: Hi I haven't included that in the code. The results am getting is basically the whole lot. It is as if no filtering is working.

Comment: Hi again I think there is something wrong before that. I.e every single content coming back has object.bookmarked = YES even though I have set it to NO by default. I will need to check it out. I reckon , the predicate is working. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Hah it is working fine now. stupid me forgot to reset the db from the simulator first doh!! Anyways the code above is fine.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it happened coz of assign value in Object is wrong when saving.

You have to save like this

```
YourNSMNanagedObject.visibleBoolean = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithBool:false]
```

Then all predicate will work when fetching.

E.g.

```
// Filter only unvisible item
NSPredicate *favouriteFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"visibleBoolean==NO"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I keep getting bit by this one and it's not always clear that booleans in core data get saved as NSNumbers.

For the most part I make sure when creating entities I set @NO for any Boolean properties but there's always the case where I spend a whole bunch of time trying to figure out why a test doesn't pass when I've forgot to set @NO on entity creation.

This might not be the best choice for clear code but I've now started to always use != predicates for booleans in core data like (isCompleted != YES) instead of (isCompleted == NO). The fact nil == false pattern is true everywhere else but not in core data predicates and properties can be very confusing.