# How to write a BOOL predicate in Core Data?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data, predicate

I have an attribute of type `BOOL` and I want to perform a search for all managed objects where this attribute is `YES`.

For string attributes it is straightforward. I create a predicate like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userName = %@", userName];
```

But how do I do this, if I have a bool attribute called *selected* and I want to make a predicate for this? Could I just do something like this?

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"selected = %@", yesNumber];
```

Or do I need other format specifiers and just pass `YES`?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

From [Predicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001793-SW2):

You specify and test for equality of Boolean values as illustrated in the following examples:

```
NSPredicate *newPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"anAttribute == %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:aBool]];
NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"anAttribute == YES"];
```

You can also check out the [Predicate Format String Syntax](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1).

Comment: @inorganik I've read a similar claim [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22043435/375300). I don't know what is the reason for this but afaik it *should* work and it does for me.

Comment: @inorganik I also tried it and it worked ("it does for me"). I don't know what you tried. I'm curious about it. If you want, share a link to a test case so I can try the exact same code.

Comment: I retested and it worked... so I was wrong. Something else must have caused my case to fail. Either way +1 on your answer

Comment: @inorganik oh I see. If you find out what caused your case to fail i would love to know. Thanks for the +1! :)

Answer (score 104):

**Swift 4.0**

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "boolAttribute == %@", NSNumber(value: true))
```

Comment: Is there any way to fetch all objects for bool is equal to nil ?? Or does it always have to be either true or false ??

Comment: @ApoorvMote, as of Xcode 9.4, Swift 4, yes: if you use a regular Bool value in the predicate, items with `nil` attribute values will be found. For example, set an attribute's value to `nil` (we'll say you called it `boolAttribute` as shown in this answer). Then, create your predicate: `let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "boolAttribute == %@", boolValue)`. *Note: `boolValue` should equal `true` or `false`, NOT `NSNumber(value: boolValue)`.* The resulting predicate will be: `boolAttribute == nil`. That predicate *will* return any objects where `boolAttribute` is `nil`. Might not work forever...

Comment: This is works. You can simply use "boolAttribute == 1" format also.

Answer (score 72):

*Don't convert to NSNumber, nor use double "=="*

**More appropriate for Swift >= 4:**

```
NSPredicate(format: "boolAttribute = %d", true)
```

Note: "true" in this example is a Bool (a Struct)

Comment: should be new accepted answer. it's 2020 for pete's sake

Comment: This doesn't work for me when using an `NSPredicate` with Core Data. Only the `NSNumber` version works (@Viktor's answer).

Answer (score 19):

**Swift 3**

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "boolAttribute == %@", NSNumber(value: true))
```

---

In Swift 3 you should use `NSNumber(value: true)`.

Using `NSNumber(booleanLiteral: true)` and in general any literal initialiser directly is discouraged and for example [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint) (v. 0.16.1) will generate warning for usage `ExpressibleBy...Literal` initialiser directly:

> Compiler Protocol Init Violation: The initializers declared in compiler protocols such as `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral` shouldn't be called directly. (compiler_protocol_init)

Comment: Alternatively: `NSPredicate(format: "boolAttribute == %@", true as NSNumber)`

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4**

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "boolAttribute == %@", NSNumber(value: true))
```

**Swift 3**

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "field = %@", value as CVarArg)
```

Comment: This causes a crash with Xcode 9.3 and Swift 4.1. Use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34631602/3151675) instead.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3.0** has made a slight change to this:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "boolAttribute == %@", NSNumber(booleanLiteral: true))
```

Answer (score 2):

if you do not want to hard-code the attribute name inside the format you can use `#keyPath` with something like,

```
let samplePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K != %d", #keyPath(Foo.attr), true)
```