# Core data Fetch request error for predicate

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, database, core-data

**Need**

**I have to find the record with rec_name is "Apple 256GB Macbook" & isActive == true.**

**Fetch Request**

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "rec_name LIKE[cd] *%@* AND rec_name LIKE[cd] *%@* AND isActive = %@","apple","macbook",true)
```

**Error**

```
Unable to parse the format string "rec_name LIKE[cd] *%@* AND rec_name LIKE[cd] *%@* AND isActive = %@"
```

**Thank you,**

Comment: A placeholder for a `Bool` is `%d` or `%ld` rather than `%@`

Comment: @vadian, thanks for your help but still it is not working!

Comment: Try this :         let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "rec_name LIKE[cd] *%@* AND rec_name LIKE[cd] *%@* AND isActive = %@","apple","macbook",NSNumber(booleanLiteral: true))

Comment: try this 
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "rec_name LIKE[cd] %@ AND rec_name LIKE[cd] %@ AND isActive = %d","apple","macbook",true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of `*%@*` here `%@` between the `*` is not replaced by a string argument so `NSPredicate` is not able to make your query `LIKE *apple*` and `LIKE *macbook*` what you need to do is make a search string with wildcards and with Like simply use `%@`, also as @Vadian suggested use number instead of `Bool`.

```
let searchkeyword1 = "apple"
let searchkeyword2 = "macbook"

//Make search string wildcards charaters
let searchString1 = "*\(searchkeyword1)*"
let searchString2 = "*\(searchkeyword2)*"

fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "rec_name LIKE[cd] %@ AND rec_name LIKE[cd] %@ AND isActive = %@", searchString1,searchString2, true as NSNumber)
```

Also batter option here is you can use `CONTAINS` and no need to use of wildcards.

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "rec_name CONTAINS[cd] %@ AND rec_name CONTAINS[cd] %@ AND isActive = %@", "apple","macbook", true as NSNumber)
```

You can do one more thing if you want to find all record start with apple and end with macbook then you can simply use `BEGINSWITH` and `ENDSWITH`

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "rec_name BEGINSWITH[cd] %@ AND rec_name ENDSWITH[cd] %@ AND isActive = %@", "apple","macbook", true as NSNumber)
```

Comment: Better: `NSNumber(value: true)` or `true as NSNumber`, compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/42933246/1187415. There is usually no reason to call the "xxxLiteral" initializers, they are required only for the compiler.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the suggestion, edited answer with it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
fetchRequest.predicate =  NSPredicate(format: "rec_name LIKE[cd] %@ AND rec_name LIKE[cd] %@ AND isActive = %@","apple","macbook",NSNumber(booleanLiteral: true))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a predicate query like following:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "rec_name == %@ AND isActive == %@" , "Apple 256GB Macbook", NSNumber(booleanLiteral: true))
```

I don't think we need to use Like if you are looking for perfect match.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSPredicate(format: "rec_name == %@ AND rec_name == %@ AND isActive = %d","apple","macbook",true)
```