# App crash on sign in (xcode 9.3) EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1)

Tags: swift, xcode9.3

I'm getting this crash on 9.3 update, on 9.2 everything worked fine. What can it be? The error appears on sign in through any source (login pass, VK, google)

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

private let settingsManager = SettingsManager.manager

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

//  Googole Map
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("-k")

    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2069905996, green: 0.2386507988, blue: 0.3337202668, alpha: 1)

    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2069905996, green: 0.2386507988, blue: 0.3337202668, alpha: 1)

    let barFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes =  [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1), NSFontAttributeName: barFont]


    if settingsManager.isFirstStartApp {

    } else {

        settingsManager.isFirstStartApp = true
        settingsManager.setDefaultSettings()

    }

    // Facebook
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    // Google +
    var configureError: NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(String(describing: configureError)) )")
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    return true
}
```

Error in the first application method when signing throug google. I've searched some topics - no luck. Conversion to Swift 4 - no luck. Any ideas?

Crash log [pastebin.com/DEEeQnZB](http://pastebin.com/DEEeQnZB)

With the accepted answer I got further, bbut now it crashes on

```
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isActive == %@", true as CVarArg)
```

with the same "Bad access"

UPD: The issue is resolved by replacing

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isActive == %@", true as CVarArg)
```

to

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isActive == true")
```

Comment: Do you have a crash log?

Comment: Found it https://pastebin.com/DEEeQnZB

Comment: I've had a few issues using the Facebook and Google SDK while using 9.3 beta, as well as with other third party libraries. I reverted back to Xcode 9.2 as a result.

Comment: https://bugs.swift.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SR-7240

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have a similar issue with Facebook login - a work for me was found in the Xcode 9.3 release notes:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1

To quote them

> In circumstances where protocol methods or base class methods defined
>   in Objective-C claim to take non-null arguments of type id in their
>   headers, but get invoked with nil values at runtime, Swift code
>   compiled by Xcode 9.3 that overrides those methods may crash when the
>   Swift implementations are invoked. (38675815) Workaround: Change the
>   Swift override to take a value of type Any?. For example, if you
>   implement the UIApplicationDelegate protocol's
>   application(_:open:sourceApplication:annotation:) method:

```
class AppDelegate: UIApplicationDelegate {
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

> The program may crash when passed nil as the annotation argument.
>   Avoid the crash by making the annotation argument have type Any?:

```
class AppDelegate: UIApplicationDelegate {
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any?) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: Well, I'm certainly got further, but now it crashes on "let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isActive == %@", true as CVarArg) " with the same error

Comment: Thank you! It works!! I had same problem when I use branch IO link with latest updated Xcode9.3. I am getting warning saying that "has different optionality than expected by protocol 'UIApplicationDelegate'" How can we make this warning silent?

Comment: @spohn Thank you! Works, but an having same problem as Abhishek

Answer (score 4):

The crash is because of change in Xcode 9.3 swift compilation for ojective -c protocol base methods. So if the crash on app start in `AppDelegate.swift` file change the following function

> func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

to

> func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any?) -> Bool {

So basically you have to add `?` after `Any`

> Note Most important point:- You also have to remove the all Exception from the `Show the Breakpoint navigator`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The below change fixed my NSPredicate issue.

from:

```
NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@", #keyPath(PlayerMO.isSelected), true as CVarArg)
```

to:

```
NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@", #keyPath(PlayerMO.isSelected), NSNumber(value: true))
```

Found the answer here: [How to write a BOOL predicate in Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34631602/4161881)