# Bad access when creating NSPredicate instance

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, nspredicate, swift4.1

So this is the code which worked in Xcode 9.2:

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<MyModel> = MyModel.fetchRequest()
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "saved = %@", true as CVarArg)
```

and after update to Xcode 9.3 and Swift 4.1, the code crashes:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1 , address=0x1)

This is the part which crashes

```
NSPredicate(format: "saved = %@", true as CVarArg)
```

The saved property of a MyModel entity is declared as boolean. Why this started happening but it worked before ?

Comment: Use `NSNumber(value: true)` instead. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34631602/3151675

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to overcomplicate it, if you're always looking for saved = true then just use a string literal in your predicate.

```
NSPredicate(format: "saved == true")
```