# IOS/Objective C: Coredata NSPredicate with boolean

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have a boolean attribute in Coredata named "hide". In the `nsmanagedobject` file, the variable is an `NSNumber`.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *hide;//bool
```

In some cases, I want to exclude or "hide" items where the value of hide is 1.
The predicate I am using for this is:

```
hideClause = @"hide != 1";
hidePred =  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:hideClause];
```

However, the logic is not working as expected.  The FRC is not returning items even when I know for sure the value of hide is not 1.

Can anyone see what might be wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8784043/1801544 ?

Answer (score 0):

Use below predicate :

```
hidePred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"hide != %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]
```

Comment: Tried but no luck.  Same result.

Comment: Try [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (hide == %@)", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]